# Are different ports on the same server considered cross-domain? (Ajax-wise)

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

Can XMLHttpRequest send a request to `http://mydomain.example:81/` from `http://mydomain.example/`?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

For two documents to be considered to have the same origin, the protocol (http/https), the domain and the port (the default 80 or :xx) have to be indentical.
So no, you cannot use xhr against a different port.

Comment: Note that IE6 under certain security settings lets you request a different port on the same domain.