# Getting current domain in web application's web.xml

Tags: servlets, web.xml

I have a web application that performs ajax request to a web service on a different port (i.e. my application and the server are [on different domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077218/are-different-ports-on-the-same-server-considered-cross-domain-ajax-wise)).
I have not access to the server APIs, so I cannot use [JSONP](http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/).
I am resolving using the [Smiley's HTTP Proxy Servlet](https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet), so my web.xml file contains this section:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rs</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy.ProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetUri</param-name>
        <!-- my servlet is hosted at http://my_ip:my_port/webapp -->
        <param-value>http://my_ip:other_port/rest-services/rs</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rs</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Unfortunately I have to deploy the web application on different machines (development, test, production), that respond to different IP addresses.
Is there a way to make the IP address change dinamically in the web.xml file, or to retrieve the current domain somehow? Or do I have to manually change the IP address every time before compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution by myself.

I just had to replace the IP with localhost:

```
<param-value>http://localhost:other_port/rest-services/rs</param-value>
```

(it seems like a stupid answer for a stupid question, but I was sure I already tried that on the past and failed. Now it seems to work.)