# Cross-Origin Request Blocked - NodeJs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, iis, mean-stack

I'm having an issue with my MEAN stack app on the AWS - Windows. So, I've placed a port 3000 for Node server to listen, and IIS is using port 80 by default.

Then when I start the node server to listen, and fire the app I want to GET some data with Angular through Node. I'm trying with this:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/get_data').success(function(response) { // something with response });
```

This reproduce an error in my console:

[image]

This is a blocker for me, I would really appreciate if someone can point me to the right way.

I'm also interested to know why this is happening, why I'm getting CORS with port different then default (80)?

Thanks

Comment: google that error .... it comes up numerous times a day here and there is no end of answers available

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice node.js package called [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors). You can make use of this library in following way

```
var cors = require('cors')
app.options('/get_data', cors());
app.route('/get_data').get(cors(), doOperation());
```

Comment: I will try this approach and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable Cross origin request at node side by using `CORS` module.
Read more about the module and documentation here: [Enable cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Did you put `app.use(cors())` before all api's ?

Comment: I start `app = Express();` and then `app.use(cors());`.
I'm also interested to know why this is happening, why I'm getting CORS with different port?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077218/are-different-ports-on-the-same-server-considered-cross-domain-ajax-wise

Comment: This is because of security reasons. Browsers don't allow cross-origin requests .Read about it here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/